# $.Ajax posting string as array to PHP script

Tags: arrays, ajax, string, post

I am trying to get Ajax to post a set of strings to my PHP script but the var_dump of POST results in array{0}. If I try to json_decode Post I get json_decode expects parameter 1 as string but array given. 
If I console log the stringify variable I get the result I want displayed in the console. I can't seem to get Ajax to post that string to the PHP script, the code is below

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('button[id=add]').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

  var form_data = { 
      submit: $('input[name=submit]').val(),
      id: $('input[name=id]').val(),
      name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
      price: $('input[name=price]').val(),
      quantity: $('input[name=quantity]').val()
      };

   var json_data = JSON.stringify(form_data);

  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST', 
     url: 'test.php', 
     dataType: 'json', 
     data: json_data,          
     success: function(data){
      console.log(data)
        }
       });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Post `form_data`.

Comment: form_data is an array, I want to string it for my PHP script

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

The `$_POST` is only populated when you send `x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`. You're sending JSON. Don't send JSON

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button[id=add]').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

  var form_data = { 
      submit: $('input[name=submit]').val(),
      id: $('input[name=id]').val(),
      name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
      price: $('input[name=price]').val(),
      quantity: $('input[name=quantity]').val()
      };


  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST', 
     url: 'test.php', 
     dataType: 'json', 
     data: form_data ,          
     success: function(data){
      console.log(data)
        }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: Musa, posting the form_data gives me an array object which is shown when I var_dump POST. I need the the array as a string variable

Comment: In addition to what is in the answer

Comment: So where would I put the $var = json_encode($_POST) code? Would data: $var?

Comment: In test.php, and use  `form_data` in the JavaScript

Comment: that's where I get []

Comment: So if you do a `var_dump($_POST)` you see the data but echoing `json_encode($_POST)` gives you just an empty array?

Comment: var_dump gets array(0) { }, echo gets [], in my browser under 'response' I get the full array when I click the button but after I go to test.php then I get var_dump gets array(0) { }, echo gets []

Comment: Your first comment says that you see the object when you do a var_dump, or did I read that wrong?

Comment: You read it right, I thin I got confused about the page I where I click on the object button which then shows the array in the browser but on the test.php page where the PHP script is the output is var_dump gets array(0) { }, echo gets [].